# Как уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery?

Answer (score 2):

```js
if (window.addEventListener) window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', wheel, false);
window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = wheel;

function wheel(event) {
  var delta = 0;
  
  if (event.wheelDelta) delta = event.wheelDelta / 120;
  else if (event.detail) delta = -event.detail / 3;

  handle(delta);
  
  if (event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();
  event.returnValue = false;
}

function handle(delta) {
  var time = 1000;
  var distance = 300;

  $('html, body').stop().animate({
    scrollTop: $(window).scrollTop() - (distance * delta)
  }, time);
}
```

```css
#myDiv {
  height: 800px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #CCF;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS';
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 24px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
```

Как вариант можно еще посмотреть тут: http://codepen.io/JTParrett/pen/BkDie

Comment: Тут идет у объекта, а необходимо общий скролинг замедлить, который появляется справа на любом сайте.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/promatik/NFk2L/

Comment: Супер, то, что нужно. А как сделать более плавный переход?
____

А нет, все отлично и так.

Comment: Варьировать time/distance, смотря о какой плавности речь.
time - время реакции
distance - шаг

Answer (score 2):

Сделал без jQuery, с ним было бы аналогично.
На изменение размера окна не реагирует - надо обрабатывать отдельно.

Левый блок (с классом `slow`) прокручивается в 2 раза медленнее правого, при этом браузерная плавная прокрутка не портится и всё получается красиво. Даже инерция в мобильном сафари (`-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch`) работает правильно.

Если нужна поддержка старых браузеров, то можно заменить трансформацию абсолютным или относительным позиционированием, только стоит учитывать, что они могут отрицательно сказаться на производительности - это всё-таки скролл.

```js
var slow = document.querySelector(".slow");
var elem = slow.firstElementChild;

var h = slow.scrollHeight * 2 - slow.clientHeight;

slow.insertAdjacentHTML(
  'afterbegin',
  "<div class='size-doubler' style='height:" + h + "px'></div>"
);

slow.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
  elem.style.transform = 'translateY(' + slow.scrollTop / 2 + 'px)';
})
```

```css
html, body, section {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

section {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  overflow: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

article {
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: justify;
}

.size-doubler {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<section class="slow">
  <article>
    Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery?
  </article>
</section>
<section>
  <article>
    Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery? Как можно уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы колесиком мыши с помощью jQuery?
  </article>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Более плавно получается через скрипт от Tilda.
https://tildoshnaya.com/modification/softscroll

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы.

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/875889)