# Как сделать плавную прокрутку внутри блока при скроллинге мыши?

Tags: javascript, css

У меня есть блок (div), у него есть вертикальная полоса прокрутки, как сделать так, чтобы при скроллинге блока, сам скроллинг шёл плавно, при этом безо всяких якорей. То есть я поворачиваю колёсико вниз а страница плавно прокручивается.

Comment: Ваш вопрос про снижение скорости прокрутки повторяется с [#359616](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/359616)

Comment: @DenisPupyrev, вроде не похоже. Впрочем, интересный вопрос - ответил там.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let box = document.querySelector(".customScrollBox");

box.addEventListener("wheel", event => {

  let dir = event.deltaY > -1,
      road = box.scrollHeight - box.offsetHeight,
      scrollTop = box.scrollTop;
      
  if ((dir && road == scrollTop) || (!dir && scrollTop == 0)) {
    return
  }
  
  event.preventDefault();
  
  let step = box.scrollHeight / 100 * 10,
      speed = 4;
      
  for (let i = 0; i <= step; i++) {
    setTimeout(()=>dir ? box.scrollTop++ : box.scrollTop--, speed * i);
  }
  
})
```

```css
.customScrollBox {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 180px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}

.customScrollBox > div {
  height: 160px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: green;
}

.customScrollBox > div:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: blue;

}
```

```html
<div class="customScrollBox">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```