# Изменить дистанцию прокрутки

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как можно изменить дистанцию/расстояние которое будет проходить скролл на элементе при 1 прокруте колеса мыши?
Интересны все возможные способы, но в предпочтение самое простое.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/359616/178988

Comment: @Духсообщества, да вообще-то всё понятно.

Comment: @Qwertiy то что нужно. Спасибо!

Comment: @Qwertiy а может как дубликат лучше закрыть?

Comment: Если "самое простое", то зайти в настройки мыши в системе и изменить число строк прокрутки в параметрах поворота колесика ;)